# Parameter null in the child lightning controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I developed a child lightning component which is used from a parent lightning component.

I mean that the parent lightning component calls the child lightning component and give to it a value which is a parameter in the child lightning component. The value is an `Id`.

My problem is that the value (`Id`) in the init method of the child lightning controller is `null`.

But if I display the value in the view of the child lightning component, it is OK, the value is not `null`.

Can someone explain me why?

The `init` method of the child lightning component is run before the `init` method of the parent lightning component?

This is my code.

**Parent LightningCntroller**

```
({
  init: function (component) {
// Get cookies
const opportunityName = "opportunityId";
var name = opportunityName + "=";
var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');

for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
    c = c.substring(1);
  }
  if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
    const opportunityId = c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    component.set("v.opportunityIdToUse", opportunityId);
  }
}
}
})
```

**Parent Lightning Component**

```
<c:Cart opportunityId="{!v.opportunityIdToUse}" />
```

**Child Lightning Component**

```
<aura:component controller="CartCtrl" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

<aura:attribute name="opportunityId" type="String" default=""/>

{!v.opportunityId} => the value is not null

</aura:component>
```

**Child JS Controller**

```
({
  init: function (component) {
        console.log("valeur cart", component.get("v.opportunityId")); => value is null
        ...
    }
})
```

Comment: You can format your code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or clicking the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: I don't have the button and if I press Ctrl-K, the url of my browser opens itself. :(

Comment: @AurélienLaval I have formatted the post for you, so you may like to review the changes as how it was done, so that you can utilize it in future. As for your question, it's not clear if the `init` function of Child is actually called during Child's initialization. We'll need to see a bit of more code of the Child Component.

Comment: I added the controller of the parent lightning component in my first post.

Comment: I dont't have lot of code in the child component.

Comment: @AurélienLaval Still. Providing that will help to know how is the attribute declared and when is the `init` on Child invoked.

Comment: I just added more code.

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is the expected behavior.

If you have a nested component (which is your case here), the `init` of the nested component gets fired before the containing component.

So as you instantiate the child component in the parent component using `<c:Cart opportunityId="{!v.opportunityIdToUse}" />`, it invokes the `init` of child first.

Now, you are only setting the value of `opportunityIdToUse` in the parent's `init` function, it would have never been made available in child's `init`.

The below links should help to understand this behavior in details:

- [Events Fired During the Rendering Lifecycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_lifecycle.htm?search_text=lifecycle)
- [Invoking Actions on Component Initialization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_init_handler.htm)

  > If a component is contained in another component or app, the inner component is initialized first.

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand, I will update my code to match with that.

Thank you.